# Android Hieve has stopped - Android development error?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

I have downloaded the code for android app from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

And i had run this code in my eclipse but i had recieved some errors.
Here i am giving you log cat of project.

```
11-27 11:15:59.549: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:15:59.589: D/gralloc_goldfish(913): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-27 11:16:03.049: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:16:05.910: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:16:06.030: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:16:08.874: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(913): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
11-27 11:16:08.874: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(913):   in android.widget.EditText{40d0a440 VFED..CL .F....I. 8,99-232,129 #7f080002 app:id/txtEmail}
11-27 11:16:08.874: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(913):   0: sent at 138840000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=138840, downTime=138687, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
11-27 11:16:11.334: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:16:11.846: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:16:12.374: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:16:12.775: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:16:15.032: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:16:15.815: D/dalvikvm(913): GC_CONCURRENT freed 206K, 13% free 2550K/2900K, paused 109ms+12ms, total 235ms
11-27 11:16:16.370: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:16:18.554: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:16:19.490: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:16:20.714: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:16:23.045: I/Choreographer(913): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:16:24.014: I/dalvikvm(913): Could not find method com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkDevice, referenced from method com.androidhive.pushnotifications.MainActivity.onCreate
11-27 11:16:24.014: W/dalvikvm(913): VFY: unable to resolve static method 110: Lcom/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar;.checkDevice (Landroid/content/Context;)V
11-27 11:16:24.014: D/dalvikvm(913): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0040
11-27 11:16:24.064: I/dalvikvm(913): Could not find method com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.onDestroy, referenced from method com.androidhive.pushnotifications.MainActivity.onDestroy
11-27 11:16:24.064: W/dalvikvm(913): VFY: unable to resolve static method 114: Lcom/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar;.onDestroy (Landroid/content/Context;)V
11-27 11:16:24.064: D/dalvikvm(913): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000f
11-27 11:16:24.394: D/AndroidRuntime(913): Shutting down VM
11-27 11:16:24.404: W/dalvikvm(913): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-27 11:16:24.484: E/AndroidRuntime(913):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 11:21:24.635: I/Process(913): Sending signal. PID: 913 SIG: 9
11-27 11:31:23.594: E/Trace(1311): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-27 11:31:24.385: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:24.454: D/gralloc_goldfish(1311): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-27 11:31:25.488: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:27.606: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:28.708: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:29.264: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:30.398: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:32.590: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:35.235: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 103 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:36.295: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:36.875: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 148 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:40.458: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 92 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:42.064: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:43.116: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:43.629: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:44.166: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:46.287: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:47.344: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 98 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:48.396: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:49.486: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:50.076: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 95 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:51.190: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 97 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:51.686: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:57.468: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:31:58.479: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:01.720: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:02.269: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:03.344: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:05.441: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 86 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:06.005: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:07.055: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 103 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:13.433: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:13.996: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:14.524: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:15.586: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:18.745: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 90 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:21.374: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 92 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:22.457: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 92 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:23.114: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 169 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:23.614: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 96 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:24.184: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:25.338: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:26.884: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:27.114: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 151 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:28.234: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1311): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
11-27 11:32:28.234: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1311):   in android.widget.EditText{40d0e9c8 VFED..CL .F....I. 8,99-232,129 #7f080002 app:id/txtEmail}
11-27 11:32:28.234: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1311):   0: sent at 1118162000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=1118162, downTime=1117979, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
11-27 11:32:28.234: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1311):   -- recent events --
11-27 11:32:28.234: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1311):   1: sent at 1112966368000, MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=51.0, y[0]=14.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=1112966, downTime=1112882, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
11-27 11:32:28.234: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(1311):   2: sent at 1112882632000, MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=51.0, y[0]=14.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=1112882, downTime=1112882, deviceId=0, source=0x1002 }
11-27 11:32:28.404: D/dalvikvm(1311): GC_CONCURRENT freed 197K, 12% free 2555K/2896K, paused 99ms+4ms, total 166ms
11-27 11:32:28.624: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 106 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:29.094: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:29.268: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:30.686: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 135 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:32.865: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 122 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:33.555: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:34.355: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:34.874: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 91 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:38.534: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:39.054: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:39.555: I/Choreographer(1311): Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-27 11:32:39.635: I/dalvikvm(1311): Could not find method com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkDevice, referenced from method com.androidhive.pushnotifications.MainActivity.onCreate
11-27 11:32:39.635: W/dalvikvm(1311): VFY: unable to resolve static method 110: Lcom/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar;.checkDevice (Landroid/content/Context;)V
11-27 11:32:39.635: D/dalvikvm(1311): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0040
11-27 11:32:39.635: I/dalvikvm(1311): Could not find method com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.onDestroy, referenced from method com.androidhive.pushnotifications.MainActivity.onDestroy
11-27 11:32:39.644: W/dalvikvm(1311): VFY: unable to resolve static method 114: Lcom/google/android/gcm/GCMRegistrar;.onDestroy (Landroid/content/Context;)V
11-27 11:32:39.644: D/dalvikvm(1311): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000f
11-27 11:32:40.015: D/AndroidRuntime(1311): Shutting down VM
11-27 11:32:40.025: W/dalvikvm(1311): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.androidhive.pushnotifications.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-27 11:32:40.084: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 11:32:46.704: I/Process(1311): Sending signal. PID: 1311 SIG: 9
```

warnings

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method setLatestEventInfo(Context, CharSequence, CharSequence, PendingIntent) from the type Notification is deprecated  GCMIntentService.java   /AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM/src/com/androidhive/pushnotifications line 104    Java Problem
The method setButton(CharSequence, DialogInterface.OnClickListener) from the type AlertDialog is deprecated AlertDialogManager.java /AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM/src/com/androidhive/pushnotifications line 31 Java Problem
The constructor Notification(int, CharSequence, long) is deprecated GCMIntentService.java   /AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM/src/com/androidhive/pushnotifications line 94 Java Problem
The field PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated WakeLocker.java /AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM/src/com/androidhive/pushnotifications line 13 Java Problem
```

Please help

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar`, add gcm.jar file to the libs folder and make sure that it is checked in private libraries

Comment: I had done the same already but still error shows in emulator Unfortunately, Android Hieve has stopped - Android development error

Comment: There are four warning also

Comment: 1) Description Resource Path Location Type
The constructor Notification(int, CharSequence, long) is deprecated GCMIntentService.java /AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM/src/com/androidhive/pushnotifications line 94 Java Problem

Comment: 2) Description Resource Path Location Type
The field PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated WakeLocker.java /AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM/src/com/androidhive/pushnotifications line 13 Java Problem

Comment: 3)Description Resource Path Location Type
The method setButton(CharSequence, DialogInterface.OnClickListener) from the type AlertDialog is deprecated AlertDialogManager.java /AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM/src/com/androidhive/pushnotifications line 31 Java Problem

Comment: 4) Description Resource Path Location Type
The method setButton(CharSequence, DialogInterface.OnClickListener) from the type AlertDialog is deprecated AlertDialogManager.java /AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM/src/com/androidhive/pushnotifications line 31 Java Problem

Comment: Warnings should go into the question body, not added as comments!